# Podemos aceitar perguntas que pedem descrição que existe em documentação?

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

Vejam este caso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15587/para-que-serve-esse-comando-jsp

É, a pergunta não é das melhores, ela é bem básica. Ela pede basicamente o que pode ser achada em documentação em pesquisa simples. Mas a documentação está em inglês. Aparentemente não há nada útil facilmente encontrado em português.

Mas será que os problemas dela são suficientes para fechá-la?

Ou realmente é um abuso pedir por documentação (descrição, não o link, acho que o link já está claro que não pode)?

O usuário não sabe inglês. Mas não dá para programar sem saber o mínimo de inglês. E existe o tradutor. É ruim, mas o programador que não aprende o mínimo de inglês para ler documentação merce nossa ajuda para resolver o problema de língua dele? Estamos ajudando ele com programação ou com a dificuldade da língua? O SOpt foi criado para resolver todos os problemas de língua dos programadores ou só para a dificuldade de expressão em outra língua?

Deixar a pergunta aberta vai causar algum mal ao site?

E se isso virar uma bola de neve? E se esse ou outros usuários começarem perguntar o mesmo sobre todas as classes e métodos de toda uma API ou *framework*? Ou ainda outras explicações básicas. Veja: [Explicação sobre um comando JSP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15610/explicacao-sobre-um-comando-jsp)

Dá para reabrir a pergunta ou é melhor que ela permaneça fechada? Essa ação provavelmente vai criar "jurisprudência" para casos semelhantes. Então precisamos decidir bem.

Comment: Fiquei a pensar o mesmo quando vi a pergunta. E nem opinião tenho sobre o que fazer.

Comment: Tenho medo justamente da bola de neve, pois baseado nisso alguém pode chegar e criar 80 mil perguntas pedindo a definição de cada comando de determinada linguagem de programação.

Comment: Ah, não, preguiça manda lembranças... Se fosse "estou tentando usar o comando tal e não entendo esta parte da documentação", que é mais ou menos o que acontece no segundo exemplo, acho que tudo bem. Mas "me dá o link da documentação e me explica tudo" merece chuva de votos negativos e fechamento ultra-rápido.

Comment: Não sei se é exatamente preguiça (me deu até um pouco de dó, tanto que respondi a segunda pergunta citada), pode ser absoluta falta de saber como encontrar a informação. Mesmo assim, não sei se cabe a este site resolver isso.

Comment: Eu as vezes mesmo em inglês tenho dificuldade em perceber para que serve uma funcionalidade, e as vezes nem é pelo inglês, é mesmo pela fraca explicação encontrada na documentação. E as vezes encontram-se umas coisas interessantes do SOEN, com excelentes respostas. É um assunto complicado. Mas talvez se devesse manter as perguntas desse tipo que demonstrem que foi feito o trabalho de casa. O que não parece acontecer no primeiro caso.

Comment: Esse é o tipo de situação que poderia ser facilmente resolvida se as pessoas tivessem bom senso... Como já comentei antes, não dá pra aprender programação "uma pergunta por vez", então se um mesmo usuário começar a fazer um monte de perguntas desse tipo, isso não deveria ser aceito. Por outro lado, pelo [Princípio de Pareto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_de_Pareto) uma parte pequena da API seria responsável pela maior parte dos usos corriqueiros, de modo que não acredito que viraria uma bola de neve. Entretanto, esse tipo de "regra informal" é difícil de ser institucionalizada...

Comment: Eu acho que a gente devia ter uma resposta padrão para certos casos. Se os links para o LMGTFY não fossem bloqueados no SE, eu teria usado naquele comentário na pergunta citada.

Comment: Quero retratar-me um pouco, o conceito "chuva de votos negativos" é puro SOEN e não tem cabimento na gestação deste site. O que não quer dizer que eu não vote negativamente se o placar de um post ruim for `>= 0`, pois não acredito numa atitude *tudo azul* nem que VN sejam uma afronta ou mau uso do site.

Comment: Maio tarde pra comentar mas vamos lá. Eu sempre tive uma paciência de Jó com essa espécie de programador (sim, pejorativamente) mas sempre detestei isso. Programar não é decoreba, somos humanos e temos nossos lapsos de vez em sempre (o.O). No modelo do SO, esse comportamento serve unicamente como *reputation mining* onde  a pessoa mais desocupada, digo, com mais tempo livre e que vir a pergunta primeiro e bater a resposta mais rapidamente com links e tal, vai coletar quantidades ridículas de pontuação e foi por essas e outras que o fórum de onde eu vim fracassou com sistema de reputações.